# EMI EMC analysis of converters

Tags: dc-dc-converter, emc, power-integrity

Probably not the best place to ask this question, I'll remove it if not received well.

I am trying to perform EMI/EMC analysis of my resonant buck converter PCB. I tried to use ANSYS SIwave for this, but I'm not able to find much documentation on it to clarify my specific doubts, I even tried asking it [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/524536/far-field-simulation-results) before. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what software I could use for this? I'm nor currently in a position to perform hardware tests due to the pandemic.

Comment: *Does anyone have any suggestions as to what software I could use for this?* Asking for products is Off-Topic here. What works for me might not work for you.

Comment: Your Y axis seems to be dB, which is a unit of power. You might like to see a dB vs V vs Frequency table at the end of my answer to the following Q&A: ***DIY Rpi Triple Axis RF / EMF Detector using AD8362 / AD8361*** - EESE 2020may21
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/112643/diy-rpi-triple-axis-rf-emf-detector-using-ad8362-ad8361/112647#112647. The Wiki on dB might also help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel. Cheers.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I wasn't "asking for products" I just wanted to know what other software like SIWave could be used, I haven't done this before, and SIWave seems to be a bit complex,thank you for your comment.